# asp.net mvc 3 ViewContext to new object, then changing the tempViewContext.RouteData modifies the original ViewContext

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have worked on a culture switch control and i need to modify the
ViewContext.RouteData("culture") to check if the view exists
anyway when i do the following

```
Dim routeData As RouteData = ViewContext.RouteData
routeData.Values.Remove("culture")
routeData.Values.Add("culture", cultureValue)
```

then the original ViewContext.RouteData is changed when i change the routeData.

I have tested to do the following to but no success

```
Dim tempViewContext As New ViewContext(ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext, ViewContext.View, ViewContext.ViewData, ViewContext.TempData, ViewContext.Writer)
Dim routeData As RouteData = tempViewContext.RouteData
routeData.Values.Remove("culture")
routeData.Values.Add("culture", cultureValue)
```

Do anyone know how to copy the ViewContext to a temporary object and changing the values without changing the original ViewContext values?

Edit: The only way i know work is to change the routeData then check if it exists and after
it change the routeData back to the original culture... was hopping there were a another way but it works for know.

Answer (score 0):

RouteData is supposed to be readonly. If you want to change the culture you could create a new request. So for example if you had the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{culture}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

you could send a new request: `/Home/Index/fr-FR` which will modify the corresponding route parameter.

Here's a [nice article](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) about localization that I would recommend you reading.

Comment: I already know of the article but what i was trying to do was check if the view exists im using a view engine who use the following syntax ~/views/Home/fr-FR/index and i need to know if it exists before building the link to the culture. But then i need the routeData to chance its culture to use Dim viewResult As ViewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(New ControllerContext(Context, routeData, Controller), viewName, masterName)
Return If(viewResult.View IsNot Nothing, True, False)